# how to get an array of objects from a query in PHP5.3?

Tags: php

I need a function to retrieve data from a query and send that information to the page that asks to load a table (html), I'm trying what you see, but do not get to have a result.

> CLASS PHP

```
class products {

    public $Id;
    public $sku;
    public $name;
    public $price;

    var $function_result = array();

    function getProducts() {
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "usbw", "Datos");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Error in conection: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }
        $query = "SELECT Id,sku,name,price FROM products";
        if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
            $i = 0;
            while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
                $object = new stdClass;
                $object->Id = $obj["Id"];
                $object->sku = $obj["sku"];
                $object->name = $obj["name"];
                $object->price = $obj["price"];
            }
        }
        $mysqli->close();
        return $object;
    }

}
```

> HTML (PHP)

```
        <?php
        require 'Clases/productos.class.php';
        $pro = new productos();
        $datos = $pro->getProducts();
        ?>
       <!DOCTYPE html>
             <html>
                 <head>
                   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
                 <title></title>
                 </head>
               <body>
             <?php
                 for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($datos); $i++) {
               ?>
             <p><?php echo $datos[$i]["name"]; ?></p>
              <?php
                 }
                ?>
               </body>
               </html>
```

attentive to the suggestions and help!

Thank you!
regards

mauriciohz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add each object into an array and return that. Change your getProducts function to something like this:

```
function getProducts() {
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "usbw", "Datos");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Error in conection: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $query = "SELECT Id,sku,name,price FROM products";
    $objects = array();
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
        $i = 0;
        while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
            $object = new stdClass;
            $object->Id = $obj["Id"];
            $object->sku = $obj["sku"];
            $object->name = $obj["name"];
            $object->price = $obj["price"];
            $objects[] = $object;
        }
    }
    $mysqli->close();
    return $objects;
}
```

Also, as **Mark B** has mentioned in the comments, there's no real need to create a new object to store the result from the `mysqli_fetch_object` call, at least as your code is currently written. So the while loop could really be simplified to something like this:

```
while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
    $objects[] = $obj;
}
```

Comment: there's very little point in doing all those $object->whatever assignments anyways. fetch_object already returns a stdobject, so `$objects[] = $obj` is all that should be needed.

Comment: @MarcB That's a fair point, but it's also possible this is just a simplified version of the code, and there may be other reasons for wanting to construct a new object.

Comment: @MarcB I do think it's worth mentioning though, so I've added your suggestion to the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save each row into an array. Don't forget you are generating an array of **objects**, you cannot access its elements with the square brackets:

```
class Products
{
    public $Id;
    public $sku;
    public $name;
    public $price;

    var $function_result = array();

    public function getProducts () {
        $products = array();
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "usbw", "Datos");

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Error in conection: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }

        $query = "SELECT Id,sku,name,price FROM products";

        if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
            while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
                $object = new stdClass;
                $object->Id = $obj["Id"];
                $object->sku = $obj["sku"];
                $object->name = $obj["name"];
                $object->price = $obj["price"];

                $products []= $object;
            }
        }

        $mysqli->close();

        return $products;
    }
}
```

Use the arrow operator to access the object properties:

```
require_once 'Clases/productos.class.php';
$almacen = new Productos();
$productos = $almacen->getProducts();

foreach ($productos as $producto) { ?>
    <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($producto->name)></p>
<?php }
```